# How to create a nested form based on start number in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, nested-forms, cocoon-gem

I need to preselect a value in a combo box before the has_many form is created, like this:

** Attention, I don't need any + or - buttons, just a preselected value generates the has_many form.

*** Numero de prestações** is the combo that I want to call the has_many form.
[image: first]

So, based on the  number of choosed in the past, I want to create `fields_for` the has_many association.
[image: second]

Anyone can help's me?

My code:

*Controller:*

```
def new
    @account_payable = Account.new kind: AccountKind::PAYMENT

    build_installments
end

def build_installments
  params[:number_of_installments].to_i.times do
    @account_payable.installments.new
  end

  # now I need to return to new.html.slim view, and refresh the installments fields. Because now I have a new number of installments selected.
end
```

*_form.html.slim*

```
= simple_form_for @account_payable, url: financings_accounts_payables_path do |f|
  = f.error_notification

  .form-groups
    = f.association :account_value, collection: @account_values,
                    label_method: :account_element_name, value_method: :id
    = f.input :accountable_id, collection: []
    = f.input :accountable_type, as: :hidden, 
              input_html: {value: @accountable_type}
    = f.input :description, as: :text
    = f.input :number_of_installments, collection: []

    hr
  #items
    = f.simple_fields_for :installments do |installment|
      = render 'installment_fields', f: installment
  .col-md-12
    hr
    .form-actions
      = f.button :submit
      = link_to_cancel financings_accounts_payables_path
    br
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need the actual number submitted with your form data, you could submit it to your controller remotely, and then have the controller render the form with the appropriate number of nested fields. Your controller action that renders the form would have something like this:

```
def index
  n = params[:num_children]
  n.times do
    @parent_object.build_[child_objects]
```

where [child_objects] is the nested entity.

Make sure you controller responds to javascript (`respond_to :js` at the top). And you should have `index.js.erb` that renders your form, like:

```
$(#my_form).html("<%=render 'my_form' %>")
```

Also, make sure in your `AccountsPayable` model you have this line:

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :installments
```

Comment: I've update my question!! I paste my code. I'm already doing what you said... but without success!

Comment: edited my answer to include some other stuff you might be missing. Does your console give template errors or anything like that?

Comment: The part about render is ok, I do this, and what I need to put inside 'my_form'? the whole `= simple_form_for` or just the  `= f.simple_fields_for` part? (and thanks to answer! :D)